# ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError (unknown attribute 'order_itens_attributes' for Order.):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, json, ruby-on-rails-4

please help on this issue

```
ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError (unknown attribute 'order_itens_attributes' for Order.):
```

mi code in the controller

```
  def create
    @order = Order.new(order_params)

    if @order.save
      render json: @order, include: [:user,:order_itens], status: :created, location: @order
    else
      render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end


private
 def order_params
      params.require(:order).permit(
        :user_id, :subsidiarie_id, :amount, :start_time,
         :arrive_time, :delivered_time, :cancel_time,
         order_itens_attributes: [:quantity])
 end
```

my models order.rb

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :subsidiarie, optional: true
  has_many :order_itens

end
```

model order_iten.rb

```
class OrderIten < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :order, optional: true
  belongs_to :product, optional: true
end
```

and my post request

```
{
    "order":
    {
        "subsidiarie_id":1,
        "user_id":1,

        "amount":220,
        "order_itens_attributes": 
        [
            {
                "quantity":22

            }
        ]
    }

}
```

seem that is an issue with order_itens_attributes but i dont know that its the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html read about it here basically you need to set

`accepts_nested_attributes_for :order_itens`

on your order model

Comment: Thanks a lot that was my issue

Answer (score 2):

in `order.rb` add

`accepts_nested_attributes_for :order_itens`

Comment: @JagdeepSingh Thnx :)